# Regex to match any of the following - "a","p"," am"," pm", etc

Tags: regex, debugging, syntax

I'm looking for regex that will match "a","p"," a"," p","am","pm"," am"," pm".

Note that what I'm looking for is whitespace agnostic.  I have a regex grouping within a string, what I have right now, that is not working for a/m/am/pm is this:

`/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(\s(am|pm|a|p)$)/i;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(\s*[ap]m?)$/i
```

The main change is the asterisk (`*`) after `\s`. It means - allow any number of whitespaces, or no whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this...

```
\s(am|pm|a|p)
```

to this...

```
\s?(am|pm|a|p)
```

The `?` makes the whitespace character optional. You could also use `*` instead of `?` if you wanted to potentially allow multiple spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that's whitespace-agnostic:

```
/^\s*(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{2})\s*([ap]m?)\s*$/i
```

Matches:

- `1:23 PM`
- `01:03 A`
- `10:50 pm`
- `12:20 p`
- etc.

Comment: can you explain what is `[ap]` and where can I read about it ?